# home page open problem

Tags: home, page

i have problem in my website
when i am going to open website then i am found following attachment error.
Web Url Is- www.mkzon.com
I Have Tried To Clear Cache But My Problem Is Not Solved
now what i can tried.
So Please Tell Me About My Problem.. Please..
[image: home page screen shot]

Comment: Looks like theme not configured correctly or permission issue.

Comment: you need to check your logs. looks like your default theme was incorrectly modified. do not use default theme - use child theme to easily apply any upgrades

Comment: Please, be more specific about your problem. 404? jquery error? wrong contents in page?

Comment: There is no real error in this screenshot apart from the logo not loading

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you used some jQuery functions but didn't include jQuery library file. You can check errors in console. There is one error as follows.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Or try to use **$** instead of **jQuery** to check whether it works or not.

Comment: no, $ is used by prototype, it won't work...

Comment: i guess this is not the problem